# Error on Test Class - System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject

Tags: apex, trigger

Afternoon all,

Am trying to write my first complex trigger to auto generate opportunities on activation of a contract but my test class keeps failing. I recognise the error as indicating there is nothing in the list to insert but I can't figure out where the issue is. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Trigger

```
trigger CreateContractTrigger2YearDealTerm on Contract (after insert, after update) {
    List <Opportunity> listOppor = new list <Opportunity>();
    for (Contract con : Trigger.new) {
{

   if(con.RPI__c == 'Yes' && con.ContractTerm == 24 && con.Status == 'Activated' && con.Triggers_Auto_Fired__c == FALSE && con.RPI_Trigger_Frequency__c == 'Annually')
       {
            Opportunity oppNew = new Opportunity ();
          oppNew.Type = 'Incremental Contract Trigger';

          oppNew.StageName = '10% - Gathering Info/Preparing Solution';
          oppNew.Name = con.Account +' - ' + con.Highlevel_Product_Type__c + ' - ' + oppNew.Type;
           oppNew.Service_Live_Date__c = con.StartDate.addYears(1);
           oppNew.CloseDate = con.StartDate.addDays(364);
           oppNew.Highlevel_Product_Type__c = con.Highlevel_Product_Type__c;
           oppNew.Trigger_Type__c = 'Retail Price Index';


          listOppor.add(oppNew);
       }


   if(con.PPUP_Mechanism__c == 'Yes' && con.ContractTerm == 24 && con.Status == 'Activated' && con.Triggers_Auto_Fired__c == FALSE && con.PPUP_Trigger_Frequency__c == 'Annually')
       {
            Opportunity oppNew = new Opportunity ();
          oppNew.Type = 'Incremental Contract Trigger';

          oppNew.StageName = '10% - Gathering Info/Preparing Solution';
          oppNew.Name = con.Account +' - ' + con.Highlevel_Product_Type__c + ' - ' + oppNew.Type;
           oppNew.Service_Live_Date__c = con.StartDate.addYears(1);
           oppNew.CloseDate = con.StartDate.addDays(364);
           oppNew.Highlevel_Product_Type__c = con.Highlevel_Product_Type__c;
           oppNew.Trigger_Type__c = 'Price Per Usage Point';


          listOppor.add(oppNew);
       }
    if(listOppor.size() > 0)
     insert listOppor;    

}
}
}
```

Test Class

```
@isTest

public class TestCreateOppsOnContracts24Months
{
Static testMethod void TestCreateOppsOnContracts24Months(){
    Account a = [select Id from Account limit 1];
    Contract c = new Contract();

    c.Accountid = a.id;
    c.Status = 'Activated';
    c.Contract_Sponsor__c = 'Craig Coates';
    c.StartDate = date.today();
    c.Contract_Type__c = 'IAR';
    c.ContractTerm = 24;
    c.Business_Division__c = 'Commercial Team';
    c.EndDate = c.StartDate.addYears(2);
    c.Pricing_Signed_off_by__c = 'Rate Card';
    c.Margin__c = 0.1;
    c.RPI__c = 'Yes';
    c.RPI_Description__c = 'Test RPI Description';
    c.RPI_Trigger_Frequency__c = 'Annually';
    c.PPUP_Mechanism__c = 'Yes';
    c.PPUP_Mechanism_Description__c = 'Test PPUP Description';
    c.PPUP_Trigger_Frequency__c = 'Annually';
    c.Triggers_Auto_Fired__c = FALSE;
    insert c;

    }
}
```

My Error Message

Time Started    06/10/2015 14:12
Class   TestCreateOppsOnContracts24Months
Method Name TestCreateOppsOnContracts24Months
Pass/Fail   Fail
Error Message   System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject
Stack Trace Class.TestCreateOppsOnContracts24Months.TestCreateOppsOnContracts24Months: line 6, column 1

Thanks

UPDATE

@isTest

public class TestCreateOppsOnContracts24Months
{
Static testMethod void TestCreateOppsOnContracts24Months(){
        Account testAccount = new Account();
        testAccount.Name = 'Test Account';
        insert testAccount;

```
Contract c = new Contract();
c.AccountID = testAccount.Id;
c.Status = 'Draft';
c.Contract_Sponsor__c = 'Craig Coates';
c.StartDate = date.today();
c.Contract_Type__c = 'IAR';
c.ContractTerm = 24;
c.Business_Division__c = 'Commercial Team';
c.EndDate = c.StartDate.addYears(2);
c.Pricing_Signed_off_by__c = 'Rate Card';
c.Margin__c = 0.1;
c.RPI__c = 'Yes';
c.RPI_Description__c = 'Test RPI Description';
c.RPI_Trigger_Frequency__c = 'Annually';
c.PPUP_Mechanism__c = 'Yes';
c.PPUP_Mechanism_Description__c = 'Test PPUP Description';
c.PPUP_Trigger_Frequency__c = 'Annually';
c.Triggers_Auto_Fired__c = FALSE;
insert c;

}
```

}

My only issue now is that it isn't triggering as the status is incorrect. Got any ideas on how I can insert an Activated contract for the test?

Comment: Christoph answered your question, but your test is still failing. In your updated test, you're setting `c.Status = 'Draft';` instead of `c.Status = 'Activated';` but your trigger only fires when Status is Activated. Is there a reason you are setting the status to draft?

Comment: Because when I tried to insert the Status as Activated I got the below error.

System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_STATUS, invalid status:

Comment: Please mark as answered and start a new question. Changing your original question when it was answered and asking a new on makes it difficult for others with similar issue to find an answer

Comment: Apologies, still quite new to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by default, whenever you run your tests, they [do not have access](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_data_access.htm) to any data in your org.
That said, your query

```
Account a = [select Id from Account limit 1];
```

Returns a list of size 0, which cannot be assigned to your variable "a".
To avoid this kind of error, you could employ something like

```
List<Account> accounts = [select Id from Account limit 1];
System.assertEquals(1, accounts.size()); // This will fail your test if there are no accounts
Account a = accounts.get(0);
```

To actually have test data to run your tests with, you either need to create it, or allow your tests to access your production data by adding the "[(SeeAllData=true)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_seealldata_using.htm)" annotation to your test class/method (you should not do this, if you don't have to).

To create test data, you just insert it before your run your test, for your example:

```
@isTest

public class TestCreateOppsOnContracts24Months
{
Static testMethod void TestCreateOppsOnContracts24Months(){
    Account tmp = new Account(Name = 'ACME');
    insert tmp;
    Test.startTest();

    Account a = [select Id from Account limit 1];
    Contract c = new Contract();

    c.Accountid = a.id;
    c.Status = 'Activated';
    c.Contract_Sponsor__c = 'Craig Coates';
    c.StartDate = date.today();
    c.Contract_Type__c = 'IAR';
    c.ContractTerm = 24;
    c.Business_Division__c = 'Commercial Team';
    c.EndDate = c.StartDate.addYears(2);
    c.Pricing_Signed_off_by__c = 'Rate Card';
    c.Margin__c = 0.1;
    c.RPI__c = 'Yes';
    c.RPI_Description__c = 'Test RPI Description';
    c.RPI_Trigger_Frequency__c = 'Annually';
    c.PPUP_Mechanism__c = 'Yes';
    c.PPUP_Mechanism_Description__c = 'Test PPUP Description';
    c.PPUP_Trigger_Frequency__c = 'Annually';
    c.Triggers_Auto_Fired__c = FALSE;
    insert c;
   Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can write a [test setup method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_testsetup_using.htm), that's executed before the first test method.

Comment: Thanks Christoph. I started comparing to my previous test classes and spotted the error re: the account. I ended up going with the update abobe instead which passed.